# Gnuplot: Do NOT show graph after saving into file

Tags: gnuplot

i searched for a command, but didn't find one. I just wrote a small batch script in gnuplot and have a 'data.dat' which i want to plot. The graph is saved into a file. 
Now i want that the output should not be displayed, neither for 200 ms. 
I just want it completely hidden.

Thank you for your efforts.

greetz

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong ;) Seriously: Show us your script, then we can help. I guess you are using `replot` instead of having `plot` as the last command.

Comment: yes you're right. Should've put the plot command to the bottom. thanks

Comment: Ok, I'll add that as answer so we can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are doing something like:

```
plot x
...
...
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
replot
```

This uses the default, interactive terminal for the first `plot` command. If you don't want that, you should first change the terminal and only use the `plot` command at the end:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
... 
plot x
```

Comment: Precisely what I need, here in July 2017 with gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3.  Thanks.